# Why did Rocket say, "Not it"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), the following dialogue occurs between Black Widow & Nebula:

> Black Widow: What is Vormir?
>
> Nebula: A dominion of death...at the very center of celestial existence. It's where Thanos murdered my sister.
>
> Rocket: **Not it**.

Why did Rocket say, "Not it"?

Comment: Regarding all the down votes - presumably some people think this is an obvious question? Consider that the OP (as well as many many other MCU fans) are not necessarily native English speakers. The "not it" expression is a sort of slang or jargon which some people may genuinely not understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, he didn't, it was Scott (Ant-Man) that says it. From the official script:

> **Nebula:** A dominion of death at the very center of celestial existence. *(beat)* It’s the place where Thanos murdered my sister.
>
> *That hangs heavily. A moment passes. Then...*
>
> **Scott Lang:** Not it.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame* - Official script</sub>

"Not it" is like saying I don't want to do it. From the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=not%20it):

> "Not it" exempts a person from performing a deed provided he or she is not the last person to call "not it"
>
> The last person to call not it must perform the deed at hand, provided he or she lies in the realm of responsibility)

Essentially it sounds like a terrible place but they've all got to go somewhere. Scott says "not it" because he doesn't want to go to Vormir but rather somewhere else.

Comment: I feel like the explanation from user62584 (deleted) is a good one that would add to this explanation, aside from part about OP being wrong about who said it.